# javascript function not firing from form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The javascript file is external but appears to load, if I look at the source of the page and click the js link I get the full js source

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $main_vars["site"]; ?></title>
    <link href="<?php echo $main_vars["theme"] ?>css/main.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

But it doesn't successfully call the js function from a form submit

```
<form id="register" onsubmit="submitRegister(); return false;">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Register" />
</form>
```

I have a bunch of alerts in the js that aren't firing

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Save some typing on the document elements
function _(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

/* AJAX process registration form */
function submitRegister() {

    _("button").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'Please wait ...';
  alert("In submitRegister");
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: wrap those javascripts with an event. `load` event might be a good fit your situation `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: Do you see any errors in the F12 console?

Comment: One alternative is to use `onclick` JavaScript Form Submit. Add `onclick` to submit button, use `form.submit()` method to submit form.

Comment: Thanks Nisarg, actually used the PHP concaternation character in the javascript :) No idea what the original problem was, working like a brought one now. Onto next problem with CSS.